# Requery SubForm after button is clicked on Popup box

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a navigational Form e.g. MainNavigationForm. It has multiple navigational tabs and one of the tabs have a form e.g. "MainForm". This MainForm have a comboBox where user selects a value. MainForm also has a subform e.g. "SubForm" which is hidden initially. Once user selects something from the comboBox..a Popup form pops up e.g. "PopupForm". User fills in the details on the PopupForm and once the user hits Create button on PopupForm, he should be redirected to MainForm. But this time, the SubForm should be made visible and shown the updated data using requery. So, my question is How can I requery the SubForm from the OnClick event of the Create button which is on the PopupForm??

I hope I am clear in explanation..if not..please ask more..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Got it working..Thanks to SmileyCoder

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/907826-how-requery-subform-closing-popup-form

*IF* your opening your form from code you can simply do:

docmd.OpenForm "frm_Popup",acNormal,,,acFormPropertySettings,acDialog

Me.subFrm.Requery